# Ошибка при импорте TensorFlow

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, tensorflow

TensorFlow я устанавливал таким образом:

```
C:> pip install --upgrade tensorflow // cpu
C:> pip install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu // gpu
```

Импортировал так:

```
import tensorflow as ts
```

Ошибка:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\parsers\unitest_test-weather.py", line 22, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поделюсь собственным опытом - после длительного хождения по различным граблям я остановился на следующем варианте.

- Удаляем предыдущие поломанные инсталляции Python
- Скачиваем последнюю версию Anaconda 64-bit. `Tensorflow` зависит от многих пакетов, поэтому есть смысл сразу ставить Anaconda вместо Miniconda чтобы упростить дальнейшую установку.
- Запускаем инсталляцию и следуем подсказкам.
- Запускаем `Anaconda prompt` (дальнейшие команды запускаем из под `Anaconda prompt`):

  - обновляем менеджер пакетов `conda`:

    ```
    conda update conda
    ```
  - создаем виртуальное окружение `ml` (Machine Learning) и сразу устанавливаем необходимые модули:

    ```
    conda create --name ml python=3.6 anaconda keras-gpu
    ```

Эта команда установит все необходимые модули, такие как (неполный список):

- numpy
- scipy
- numexpr
- pandas
- sklearn
- tensorflow-gpu
- keras-gpu
- matplotlib
- ipython

и много других.

Нет смысла устанавливать сразу две версии `tensorflow` (CPU и GPU) надо выбрать один из этих вариантов.

Далее прописываем путь к `%ANACONDA_DIR%\envs\ml` и к  `%ANACONDA_DIR%\envs\ml\Scripts`.

В дальнейшем для работы используем данное виртуальное окружение.

Несколько советов:

- перед обновлением модулей в виртуальном окружении всегда создавайте резервную рабочего вирт. окружения (из под `Anaconda prompt`):

  ```
  conda create --name ml_bkp --clone ml
  conda update --all -n ml
  ```

если после апдейта что-то перестало работать (такое случается), то удаляем вирт. окружение `ml` и пересоздаем его клонированием из `ml_bkp`.

Comment: спасибо за помощь.